# Select random item and index using numpy.random.choice()

Tags: python, numpy, random

I tried to implement the numpy.ramdom.choice() on a list, but I'm getting the following error:

> ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional

I have the following list of values like:
 `[-0.192, 0.23923, 0.8271, .... 0.229]`

and I want to select one those elements randomly.  I also need to retrieve the index of that random element, but I'm failing on the first step.

**My code block is:**

```
        values = []
        values.append(np.corrcoef(X, Y)[-1, :-1])

        i_column = np.random.choice(values)
```

Any advice with explanation is more than welcome.

Thanks

Comment: `values` is not 1d, maybe `np.random.choice(values[0])`.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks a lot!  Would you like to post the solution for me to mark it as the answer?